# Looping through a range to copy cells in corresponding columns when a number is found

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a user interface for making timing charts.

I have a list of processes and how long each takes.

The user will enter numbers starting at 1 in the cells to the right

[image: order of operations chart]

I'm trying to do the following:
For any row with a number copy the info from column B and F then paste it into row 39 + whatever number it finds.
This should create a list that is in the correct order in a chart.

[image: output chart]

I attempted to put together a program that loops through every row of every column in that number entry area.

```
Sub TimingChart()

Dim rng As Range
Dim cel As Range
Dim col As Range
'x is the variable for row adjustment to determine what cell to paste into
Dim x As Long
'a is the variable for column adjustments
Dim a As Long
Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("M4:AG33")

a = -11

'loop columns
For Each col In rng.Columns

'loop rows of that column
    For Each cel In col.Cells
'skip cells with nothing in them
        If cel.Value = "" Then

'any cell with a number copy the data in row B and row F and
'paste in the chart below the entry field starting in row 40
'the data should copy into row 39 + x putting the operations in order
        Else

            x = cel.Value
            cel.Offset(a, 0).Copy cel.Offset(a, 39 + x)
            cel.Offset(a + 4, 0).Copy cel.Offset(a + 4, 39 + x)
            cel.Value.Copy cel.Offset(a - 1, 39 + x)

        End If
    Next
    a = a - 1
Next col

End Sub
```

Edited to reflect removal of "range("

Comment: ...what issues are you having?

Comment: @BruceWayne I'm getting a run time error '424" object required

Comment: Where do you declare `RThisWorkbook`?  Or is that a Typo and you mean `ThisWorkbook`?  What line throws the error?  Also, you're starting at row 4...but have references to rows that would become negative, which you can't have...if I'm reading this correctly.

Comment: This can easily be done with formula, is vba necessary

Comment: the RThisWorkbook is a typo. when i fixed it it gives me run time error 1004 application defined or object defined error on the line below x = cel.Value

Comment: @ScottCraner VBA is necessary because the the numbers may be entered into any cell in the grid in any order and may have repeats

Comment: And Formulas are still possible.

Comment: It just needs to be `cel.offset` no need for the range bit. `cel.Offset(a, 0)).Copy (cel.Offset(a, 39 + x))`

Comment: @ScottCraner what formula could i use to bring one of the lines down to the output chart to the corresponding row? for example "index pallet to transfer" needs to go to row 47 and 58

Comment: @Nathan_Sav when i do that i still get the same error

Comment: See my answer below.

Comment: You are offsetting -11 from a start row of 4

Comment: You have the rows and columns switched in all you offsets.  `Offset(Row,Column)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to get the numbers put this in A39 and copy down:

```
=IFERROR(SMALL($M$4:$AG$33,ROW(A1)),"")
```

To get the Actions, put this in B29 and copy down:

```
=IF(A39<>"",INDEX(B:B,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW($M$4:$AG$33)/($M$4:$AG$33=A39),COUNTIF($A$39:A39,A39))),"")
```

To get the time, put this in F39 and copy down:

```
=IF(A39<>"",INDEX(F:F,MATCH(B39,$B:$B,0)),"")
```

So with data like:

[image]

using those formula we get:

[image]

If you really want vba then forget using offset and just refer to the column:

```
Sub TimingChart()
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        Dim rng As Range
        Set rng = .Range("M4:AG33")

        'loop columns
        Dim col As Range
        For Each col In rng.Columns

        'loop rows of that column
            Dim cel As Range
            For Each cel In col.Cells
        'skip cells with nothing in them
                If cel.Value = "" Then

        'any cell with a number copy the data in row B and row F and
        'paste in the chart below the entry field starting in row 40
        'the data should copy into row 39 + x putting the operations in order
                Else
                    'x is the variable for row adjustment to determine what cell to paste into
                    Dim x As Long
                    x = cel.Value
                    .Cells(cel.Row, 2).Copy .Cells(39 + x, 2)
                    .Cells(cel.Row, 6).Copy .Cells(39 + x, 6)
                    cel.Copy .Cells(39 + x, 1)

                End If
            Next cel
        Next col
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: what does the IFERROR(small telling excel to do?

Comment: It allows you to copy the formula down a lot of cells and if the user does not put in enough numbers to satisfy all the formula it just blanks them out instead returning an error.

Comment: BTW, this will also work if there are duplicate numbers.  It will return duplicates in order as they appear in the original list.

Comment: this works in practice, but i need it to be a VBA macro than is run when a button is pressed. then a sum is placed at the bottom

Comment: I can also place the sum dynamically at the bottom if you would like.